# Modified Counting Inversions problem using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithms, arrays, counting

> Given an array $A$, find the number of pairs $(i, j)$, such that $ i > j$ and $A[i] \ge A[j]$.

This is a modified version of the famous problem of *Counting Inversions*, only in this version it allows the elements to be equal as well. I have an algorithm for the classical counting inversions problem implemented, so i´d like to know if it can be adapted to solve this version. Thanks ahead.

Link to the algorithm (written in C++):

https://repl.it/@MateusBuarque/CountingInversion

Comment: Your link 404s so I've no idea what your algorithm is. Also, people shouldn't have to understand C++ to understand an algorithm: could you please supply the algorithm, in pseudocode, in your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is no site for "comment my code" type questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

> Can you count the number of pairs $(i,j)$ such that $A[i]=A[j]$?

Comment: yes, but only in $O(n^2)$. Oh wait, i get it now...

Comment: @MateusBuarque, well then you have something you can think about!  Spend some more time on that problem.  It's your exercise, so you'll have to find the solution yourself -- but you can do better than $O(n^2)$.